# Open Graph Protocol is not a valid XHTML 1.0 Strict?

Tags: xhtml-1.0-strict, facebook-opengraph

The protocol:

http://opengraphprotocol.org/

states the use of `<meta>` tags with the attribute `property`.

AFAIK, this is not a valid XHTML 1.0 Strict value. Is there any design decision over why it doesn't use `name` attribute instead? It looks trivial to me.

Answer (score -1):

It uses RDFa for the markup. There is an XHTML profile to allow RDFa if you really want validation.